# Sending mail with libcurl over gmail smtp gives error messages I don't understand

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, libcurl

I'm trying to send an email using libcurl through an gmail account over smtp. I'm using the precompiled binaries you can download here http://curl.haxx.se/download.html 7.39.0 for Win32 - Generic.

I tried what is described over here http://talkbinary.com/programming/c/how-to-send-email-through-gmail-using-libcurl/ but I get a different result. He basically followed the smtp-tls example of libcurl. He writes that he uncommented this line

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO,"/path/to/certificate.pem");
```

I also did that, but additionally I had to add

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
```

otherwise it says:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 173.194.65.108...
* Connected to smtp.gmail.com (173.194.65.108) port 587 (#0)
< 220 mx.google.com ESMTP cp4sm38701354wjb.16 - gsmtp
> EHLO shire
< 250-mx.google.com at your service, [84.166.177.243]
< 250-SIZE 35882577
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250-STARTTLS
< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
< 250-PIPELINING
< 250-CHUNKING
< 250 SMTPUTF8
> STARTTLS
< 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
```

So after These modifications, I get this:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 173.194.65.109...
* Connected to smtp.gmail.com (173.194.65.109) port 587 (#0)
< 220 mx.google.com ESMTP q7sm28257004wiv.8 - gsmtp
> EHLO shire
< 250-mx.google.com at your service, [84.166.177.243]
< 250-SIZE 35882577
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250-STARTTLS
< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
< 250-PIPELINING
< 250-CHUNKING
< 250 SMTPUTF8
> STARTTLS
< 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
* SSL connection using unknown / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=smtp.gm
ail.com
*        start date: 2014-07-15 08:40:38 GMT
*        expire date: 2015-04-04 15:15:55 GMT
*        issuer: C=US; O=Google Inc; CN=Google Internet Authority G2
*        SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (
20), continuing anyway.
> EHLO shire
< 250-mx.google.com at your service, [84.166.177.243]
< 250-SIZE 35882577
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
< 250-PIPELINING
< 250-CHUNKING
< 250 SMTPUTF8
> AUTH LOGIN
< 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
> bXRlY2hzeXNhZG1AZ21haWwuY29t
< 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
> anFTTzIzb1RjSDlzTU9nZDc4cnE=
< 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsb
uZo
< 534-5.7.14 7VOvzOT0OTtJcazYiOGpbaceOY427PX1CQ2gpC8wMVG5AHhSl_Hpp4pe0O1hdm5Jm5w
b9V
< 534-5.7.14 VjK_OdeEkhSuQejNA2ghBemuoPSzEXyz0ycnpQpV6Rm4Korpi5wuo4c6RcmH3o13usA
1vN
< 534-5.7.14 ryZaFNuIF8jMSXiUsiP5lPC9vK1Ll7d9fRxM_vSbIDzUOxeid1iMeBJab3us2M6RxMW
tZt
< 534-5.7.14 A5XYkt7z8nbX8W1gdCiDOGtKvqd4> Please log in via your web browser an
d
< 534-5.7.14 then try again.
< 534-5.7.14 Learn more at
< 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 q7sm2825
7004wiv.8 - gsmtp
* Authentication failed: 534
* Closing connection 0
```

I tried visiting this URL https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 and https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and tried the things written there. My Password is strong I assume. I generated it with KeePass2. I can Access that gmail account with the gmail web Interface. My Login/Password is correct. I checked multiple times now.

Comment: I just found out that gmail has a Setting where you have to enable Access from apps with less securtiy. If I toggle that Option it "works" - meaning it sends my mail. But I guess I should make my application more secure. But how?